# Como hacer que solo se ejecute una vez una accion con un Timer C#

Tags: c#

Actualmente utilizo un timer para leer el valor de una variable, con el timer hago que se actualize el valor de la variable, y si la variable es cierta manda llamar una funcion, pero se ejecuta varias veces, como puedo hacer para que solo se ejecute una vez.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        bool readDb = (bool)plc.Read("DB8.DBX0.1");
        if (readDb == true)
        {
            tbLed.BackColor = Color.Green;
            Guardar();


        }
        else
        {
            tbLed.BackColor = Color.Red;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto y no como una imágen. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y [example]

Comment: pues llama a timer1.stop() (si asi se llama tu timer)

Answer (score 0):

Un timer sirve justamente para ejecutar una función repetidas veces cada vez que pasa un intervalo de tiempo. Si lo que quieres es esperar ese intervalo y luego ejecutar algo, en su lugar usa

`await Task.Delay(int milisecondsDelay)`

Nota: El event handler debe ser `async void` para poder usar hacer `await`

Ejemplo:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000); // Esperas a que pasen los 5 segundos sin que se congele la app

    // Continuas con el resto del código luego de esperar
    bool readDb = (bool)plc. Read("DB8.DBX0.1");
    if (readDb)
    {
        tbLed.BackColor = Color.Green;
        Guardar();
    }
    else
    {
        tbLed.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```